# Java Driver class object declaration errors

Tags: java, constructor

so I'm trying to make a game in Java. I have several classes, such as a Gameloop class, a Maze class, and a Screen class that implements JFrame. Before I explain the problem here is my Driver class, its pretty simple:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Driver {
static Maze maze;
static Screen screen;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Driver.create_game();
            }
        });
    }

    protected static void create_game() {
        Driver.maze=new Maze();
        Driver.screen=new Screen(maze);
        GLoop loop= new GLoop(maze,screen);
        loop.start();
    }

}
```

the above code does not run the two constructor methods `new Maze()` or `new Screen()`
However, when I call each objects constructor on the same line as I declare them, all seems fine. Any ideas as to why this is? I can provide their constructors as well if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that main terminates before invokeLater gets a chance to run. Add after invokeLater a loop with something like a sleep(0) / yield in it